# Table view freezes when sql queries are fired in thread

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsthread

I have attached a new thread and in that thread I'm firing 5 SQLite queries.

Problem is that until execution of all my queries is finished, I'm not able to scroll the table view.  It freezes for some seconds.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(GetBackEndData) 
        toTarget:appDelegate withObject:nil];
}

// this is in appDelegate
-(void)GetBackEndData
{   
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    if([dicBarnearMe_Detail count]==0)
    {
        // this are sql queries method.
        [appDelegate SelectBeersonbottle_Count];
        [appDelegate SelectBeersonTap_Count];
        [appDelegate SelectGrowler_Count];
        [appDelegate SelectHappyHours_Count];
        [appDelegate SelectEvents_Count];

        // After completing this process I'm post notification 
        // for reloading table in other controller.
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reload" 
            object:nil userInfo:nil];
    }

    [pool release];     
}
```

Comment: let us see whats there in sql queries method....

Comment: what are you doing on main thread?

Comment: I have tried commenting this new thread line and its work fine. So, problem is attaching new thread which perform sql queries execution. On main thread i'm just reloading table.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a new thread in `viewDidAppear` and executing the `GetBackEndData` selector in separate thread.

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reload" 
            object:nil userInfo:nil];`

you making `NSNotificationCenter` in `GetBackEndData` and reloading some data that means you have to wait until your thread complete the execution and blocking UI thread.

making a thread in viewDidAppear is not a right approach you can use a dispatchQue in some other function or alternative option is wait until your thread execution get completed and show activity Indicator.